# Failure using heroku pg:transfer

Tags: ruby, heroku, pg, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to use heroku pg:transfer to transfer my local database to Heroku.

Here is the command that I'm running

```
heroku pg:transfer -f postgres://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/<db_name> -t postgres://<app_path>.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/<stuff> --app <app_name> --confirm <app_name>
```

and I'm getting the following error messages

```
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not write to output file: Invalid argument
pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

I'm using Postgres on Windows.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Import**
PG Backups can be used as a convenient tool to import database dumps from other sources to your Heroku Postgres database.

Dump your local database in compressed format using the open source [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/backup-dump.html) tool:

```
$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

**Import to Heroku Postgres**

In order for PG Backups to access and import your dump file you will need to upload it somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL. We recommend using Amazon S3.

Use the raw file URL in the `pgbackups:restore` command:

> Be sure to use single quotes around the temporary S3 URL, as it
>   contains ampersands and other characters that will confuse your shell
>   otherwise.